# Javascript resize function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-events

I run into a problem with javascript that resize elements according screen size. I would like to translate this code with same functionality to css simple class.

```
$(window).resize(function(){ // On resize
   $('item2').css({'height':(($(window).height()))+'px'});
});
```

I have tried

```
.test2 {
    height: 100%;
}
```

But doesn`t work - if I delete script part elements are not the desired with (full screen height).

Problem with script is that it implement the style to markup, which can`t be changed with media queries unless using !important...

Comment: `item2` is an tag name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you to have an element with `height` equal to screen height, you either have to set the `position:fixed` to that element and add `height:100%`, or, if you want to keep the document flow, you also need to set the document height to 100%, also all the parents of the child element have to be 100% height.

The easiest way is obviously the first approach, but that option will pull your element from the natural document flow.

```
.test2{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:100%;
    z-index:2;
}

$(window).resize(function(){
     $('item2').addClass('test2);
});
```

Keep in mind that this function is running on every resize event, which is performance costly.

To understand the issue, you can check this explanation about debouncing:
https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Comment: I used `min-height:100%;`. with fixed position as you mention and it works. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If `item2` is a `class` then you need to add `.` in the selector.

```
$(window).resize(function(){ // On resize
  //$('.item2').css({'height':(($(window).height()))+'px'});
  $('.item2').height($(window).height());
});
```

Comment: I see I forgot `.` but it doesnt solve the problem of replacing the script with pure css. Is it possible to replace `$(window).resize(function(){ // On resize
  $('.item2').css({'height':(($(window).height()))+'px'});
});`

Only with css ?

Comment: Please add the `html`.

Comment: Try the updated code by using `jQuery`s `height()` method.